# nvD3, AngularJs D3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

All --, Can any one help me to resolve the following, I am not getting where I am going wrong? My JSP page is as follows :

```
       <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">  <!-- it's important for d3.js -->
        <title><bean:message key="welcome.title" /> Dashboard</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/nv.d3.min.js"></script> <!-- or use another assembly -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/stackedAreaChart.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nv.d3.min.css"> 

        </HEAD>
        <body>
            <div ng-app='myApp'>
            <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
                <nvd3 options='options' data='data'></nvd3>
            </div>   
            </div>  
        </body>
        </html>
```

The above code displaying the stacked Area chart correctly. Then I have replaced the
above code with the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">  <!-- it's important for d3.js -->
    <title><bean:message key="welcome.title" /> Dashboard</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/nv.d3.min.js"></script> <!-- or use another assembly -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/stackedAreaChart.js"></script>     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nv.d3.min.css">     
    </HEAD>
    <body>
       <input type="button" value="Add Chart" onclick="addChart()" /> 
       <div id='myNew'>     
       </div>


    </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function addChart() {
        alert("add Chart");    
    document.getElementById('myNew').innerHTML =  '<div ng-app="myApp" >' +
        ' <div ng-controller="myCtrl">' +
' <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3> '+
' </div> ' +
' </div> ';

}
</script>
</html>
```

When I click 'Add Chart' button it should display the chart but nothing is getting displayed. Only blank page is appearing. Can any one help me how to make this to work?

I have included the stackedAreaChart.js as it is from http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/js/stackedAreaChart.js

Comment: Because your `addChart` function is not in an angular controller, therefore angular is unaware of it and can't trigger a digest cycle when clicked. Since the chart is a directive, it obviously needs to be aware of changes in scope to respond properly.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the reply and sorry for my late response. As I am relatively new to Angular JS and D3, still confused to apply your solution. could you please modify the above code to work correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$compile` service in your controller to compile the directive template with current `$scope`:

```
//javascript
$scope.onclickCreate = function(){
    var template = '<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>';
    angular.element(document.body).append($compile(template)($scope));
}
```

and chart will be created in the html body after click:

```
//html
<button ng-click="onclickCreate()">Create chart</button>
```

See live [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0XtT0f?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks krispo, it is working very well. I have replaced your example  with the data at http://jsfiddle.net/madasuk/pTGPN/  and chart type to   type: 'lineChart'. But the graph lines are getting jumbled up and y-axis not properly displaying its ticks. Could you please help me to fix this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Your example is not working, but as I can see you should sort your data, because we deal with time series. In your case it can be done like: `angular.forEach($scope.data, function(series, index){
          series.values.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0]-b[0]; }); });`. See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImbZtv?p=preview) with your data.

Comment: Thanks Krispo, I am trying to modify your code example having ng-click = onClickCreate(). I have replaced the $scope.data = getData(), where getData() brings json data using Ajax call, everything works fine. Now I have added a dropdown *** <select ng-model="myCustomer" ng-options="customer.name for customer in Customers">
      <option value="">-- choose customer--</option>
    </select>*** I am facing problem to create the chart based on the selected customer id data. How can I pass selected customer id as getData(myCustomer.id) to display the graph based on selected customer?

Comment: Resolved, I have updated the example here http://plnkr.co/edit/017pqbv1YVtB5G9TBvd3?p=preview