# nvD3, line chart, D3, angular

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, linechart, nvd3.js

Can any one help why my line chart is not plotting correctly?    I have put my code with data at :       http://jsfiddle.net/madasuk/U9KH5/4/
can any one help to plot it correctly? lines in the graph are jumbled up and tool tip is also not appearing?

```
   function addLineChart(){
        var chart;
        nv.addGraph(function() {
          chart = nv.models.lineChart()
          .options({
            margin: {left: 100, bottom: 100},
          //  x: function(d,i) { return i},
            x : (function(d,i) { 
              return new Date(d.x);
            }),
            showXAxis: true,
            showYAxis: true,
            transitionDuration: 250
          })
          ;

          // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
          chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel("Time (s)")
          //  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));
          .tickFormat(function(d) {
              return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
            });

          chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
            .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))
          //  .tickFormat(d3.format(',g'));
            ;


          d3.select('#chart1 svg')
            .datum(cumulativeMSIData())
            .call(chart);

          //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
          nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
          //nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });

          chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

          return chart;
        });


    }
```

Comment: Your example does not work.

Comment: I am relatively new to using jsfiddle and finding it difficult to make it work on jsFiddle, I am sorry for that. The graph is being displayed in my local browser with that data and function but graph lines are jumbled up and yaxis scaling and ticks are not correct. I have included relevant js files too in JsFiddle but still the graph is not getting displayed, I don't know what to do to make it work on jsfiddle. The code I have put is same as to the one at http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html  I have replaced the data there,  with my own data. Could you please help me to solve this.

Comment: I answered for your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24080976/1924674).